# Is it possible to get the current User’s roles accessible in a remote method in Loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Is it possible to get the current User’s roles accessible in a remote method in Loopback?

I’m trying to allow a remote method to either return a subset of data based on a find using a where filter & current userId but in the case of an admin user, I simply want to return a full set of data.

So I have been trying to obtain the list of roles for the current user. But I am struggling to make Role.getRoles() return anything other than:

```
[ '$unauthenticated', '$everyone' ]
```

I have tried the context from `loopback.getCurrentContext()` and the context passed into the `beforeRemote` method and I have tried `ACL.checkAccessForContext()`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can happen for many reasons, one is that the `Role` model is not related to your `User` model ([see here for brief explanation](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/968)). Can you check that?

Other than that, it's probably that first argument (context) which we need to have better documentation on ( sorry :( ). If you look at the [tests for the role class](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/test/role.test.js#L131) you can see how it might be used.

```
var RoleMapping = loopback.RoleMapping;
RoleMapping.attachTo(ds); // `ds` is your data source

// ...

Role.getRoles({principalType: RoleMapping.USER, principalId: user.id}, function(err, roles) {
    console.log(roles);  // everyone, authenticated, etc (hopefully)
});
```

Comment: Thank you @jakerella this answer was really helpful. I managed to get some valid data using – `ctx.get(‘http’).req` but I prefer your answer. I am using `isInRole` because when I use `getRoles` my admin user is being returned as an Mongo ID. I have looked at the tests (very helpful) but I do not see a simply way to return the role names instead of the IDs – I am guessing this has not been implemented thus far? Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, that method is always going to return role IDs, but you can then get the `Role` object and look at the `name` property.